# Is session in Asp.net is shared between users of the website or not?

Tags: c#, session

Is session in Asp.net is shared between users of the website or not?

Client 1 
stored value in session in page load like that:

```
 Session["editStudentID"] = editStudentID.ToString();
```

Client 2
Visiting the same page of client 1 in the same time so there will be other session stored

```
Session["editStudentID"] = editStudentID.ToString();
```

so can client 1 or 2 sessions interrupted by each other ?! or the session is unique per client

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is not shared.

The server, where the Client is sending the request to start a new Session, assigns that client a new Session ID. This is a unique ID or Token per Client. Each Post or Get to the server generally sends that Session ID or Token with it in order to tell the Server who it is(an identifier).

Also all session variable data is stored on the server.

Answer (score 3):

Session is per-session ID, and session IDs are normally per-browser (via a cookie or a URL parameter).

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not.

When a client connects to the service for the first time the initial response includes a cookie which is used to track subsequent connections from that client.  The cookie's value is then used whenever you reference the Session object to determine which data in the backing Session store is referenced.

So changing the Session data in any request will only alter it for that client.  If you need to have data shared between multiple clients you have to provide a different mechanism for doing so - a static dictionary or similar.